# highcharts-more problema con cambio de gráfica

Tags: jquery, highcharts

Buen día, estoy utilizando este ejemplo de HighCharts:
http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/chart-update/

Con 3 botones puedes cambiar el tipo de gráfica, se ve muy sencillo pero no puedo hacer que cambie a Pastel o a Puntos.
Llevo esto:

```
$("#pie").click(function () {
          chart.update({
              chart: {
                  inverted: false,
                  polar: false,
                  pie:true,
              },
              subtitle: {
                  text: "Pastel"
              }
          });
        });

        $("#bars").click(function () {
          chart.update({
              chart: {
                  inverted: true,
                  polar: false,
                  pie,false
              },
              subtitle: {
                  text: "Barras"
              }
          });
        });

        $("#web").click(function () {
          chart.update({
              chart: {
                  inverted: false,
                  pie:false,
                  polar: true
              },
              subtitle: {
                  text: "Red"
              }
          });
```

Comment: Es muy sencillo siempre y cuando repliques todo el contenido. Has visto la consola para ver posibles mensajes?

Comment: No arroja errores, sólo no pinta la gráfica.

Comment: la variable `polar` al estar en true convierte algunos tipos de gráficos en un `polar chart` los cuales son: *line, spline, column, area* pero si quieres cambiar el tipo de gráfico debes cambiarlo de la forma en que @Alberto Díaz te indicó en la respuesta que dió, ojo que también puedes cambiar el tipo en la serie y no en el gráfico, de esta forma puedes tener varios tipos de visualizaciónes en un solo gráfico

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso lo he resuelto con este código, más sencillo.

```js
$('#barras').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        }
    });
});

$('#lineas').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            type: 'line'
        }
    });
});

$('#areas').click(function () {
    chart.update({
        chart: {
            type: 'area'
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Es muy recomendable que indiques una explicacion acerca del porque de tu respuesta, te recomiendo darte una visita por el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour/) para que obtengas tu primera medalla, bienvenido!